# JSON_PARSER_ERROR on POST in Workbench

Tags: json, workbench, post

I am using https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php . Trying to add new patient, on URL /services/data/v46.0/sobjects/HealthCloudGA__EhrPatient__c, with POST method, with body like this :

```
{​ "HealthCloudGA__GivenName1__c" : "Tex",  "HealthCloudGA__FamilyName1__c" : "Willer", 
  "HealthCloudGA__BirthDate__c" : "1853-07-07" }
```

Upon execution, I get following response : JSON_PARSER_ERROR, message: `Unexpected character ('â' (code 226)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:5]`

I have also tried with no data in body (empty curly braces), and I got same result, with mention of same strange character â. It's only when I pass pure "{}" string as body, without any spaces, when request gets handled correctly. Is this a bug in Workbench itsself, or do I miss something ?

Comment: Once I also have the same issue for one of the name fields. I found one article which says "In JSON specification, it requires the use of double-quotes for field names. To enable Jackson to handle the unquoted field name, add JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES in the ObjectMapper configuration."In JSON, unquoted field names are non-standard and should be avoided. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Also try validating the JSON here https://jsonlint.com/, because I am getting an Error: Parse error on line 1:
{ ​ "HealthCloudGA__G
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'. when I am pasting your JSON here to validate.

Comment: You are right, I really had such character in my json, and none of my editors have showed it to me. But https://jsonlint.com/ did. Thanks.

Comment: Dragan or Pranav, do you want to post an answer so this question can be resolved? Thanks!

Comment: @DraganJovanović please mark a comment as useful if that helps you so that it could be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping up as an answer : "In JSON specification, it requires the use of double-quotes for field names. To enable Jackson to handle the unquoted field name, add JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES in the ObjectMapper configuration."In JSON, unquoted field names are non-standard and should be avoided.

Also try validating the JSON here jsonlint.com, because I am getting an Error: Parse error on line 1: { ​ "HealthCloudGA__G --^ Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'. when I am pasting your JSON here to validate.